# how to get unique id array retrieve from table

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I have an array of data coming from table. It has number of fields and `post_id(int)` is one them. I want to get unique value of `post_id` field of returned array.

`$data` is returned query

```
foreach ($data as $key => $get_values) {    
         $post_id = $get_values->post_id;

         $get_query = "select DISTINCT (post_id) from wp_postmeta where post_id = $post_id";

         $get_postId = mysqli_query($get_query);<br>
}
```

I want to get DISTINCT (post_id) only.

Any one have solution or any Idea?

Comment: use group by post_id clause in  your query

Comment: thnks i dnt have any idea of doing that

Comment: $get_query = "select post_id from wp_postmeta where post_id = $post_id group by post_id";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$post_id ="";
foreach ($data as $key => $get_values) {    
$post_id. = $get_values->post_id.",";
}
$post_id =substr($post_id,0,-1);
$get_query = "select DISTINCT (post_id) from wp_postmeta where post_id in ($post_id)";

$get_postId = mysqli_query($get_query);
```

Comment: Thanks, It works for me. If U can plz upvote my question. I m 2 points from 15 points so that i can upvote others answer

Answer (score 0):

The result will be returned as an array even if there is only one row returned. If you don't care which single row you want (assuming multiple match) you can use something like:

```
select post_id from wp_postmeta where post_id = $post_id limit 1
```

Assuming this is `mysql`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Select * from wp_postmeta group by post_id.

This will return all the rows with unique post_id values. Then you can loop through the array and print only those data that is required.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($data as $key => $get_values) {    
     $post_id = $get_values->post_id;

     $get_query = "select DISTINCT (post_id) from wp_postmeta where post_id = $post_id group by post_id";

     $get_postId = mysqli_query($get_query);<br>
}
```

Just add `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this Query:

SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta GROUP BY post_id